# How to save random text if the file input in twig is empty?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have an image

```
public function imageAction(Request $tequest){

     $post = new Post;
     //create form

     if($form->isSubmitted()){

          $file = $form->get("image")->getData();

           if(input_file_is_empty){

                     setImage("Some text");


               }else{
                     //get Image 
                     setImage($filename);
              }
     }
}
```

How do I make something in the controller that if clicked on button and if the file input is empty insert some text else save an image in MySQL.

Comment: Your algorythmy is good, what do you need ?

Comment: I'm stuck in code. the condition for empty file is not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `empty_data` in your form field for image. It can be of closure type in which you would then define what is a random text to you. You could then utilize the Faker library (install it through composer and inject it to a form class) if you truly need a random text or instead, return the `random text` concatenated with current timestamp with (new \DateTime)->getTimestamp() in order to get unique text over there.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#empty-data

Comment: This looks useful, one question, In the documentation, it says 'empty_data' => 'John Doe', but can I put dynamic data?

Comment: you can put a closure... instead of John Doe, function () {...}